# Можно ли пространство имен назвать библиотекой?

Tags: c#

Я описываю архитектуру программного обеспечения, вот там пишу, что для кодирование и декодирования использую System.Cryptography. Так вот, могу ли я написать так: "Используется библиотека Cryptography". Я думаю, что нет, но как тогда лучше назвать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пространства имён обычно согласуются со сборкой, в частности, предполагается, что сборка `System.Security` как раз и содержит типы из пространства имён `System.Security.Cryptography`. Но *обычно* не значит *всегда*, и в данном случае это не так: часть объектов из `System.Security.Cryptography` определена в `mscorlib`, часть в `System.Core` и часть в `System.Security`.

Сборка (assembly) находится либо в исполняемом файле (.EXE), либо в *динамически связываемой библиотеке* (.DLL). Поэтому, строго говоря, если пишете о *библиотеке*, вы должны указывать конкретную сборку, например, `mscorlib.dll`, `System.Core.dll` или `System.Security.dll`.

Можно не вдаваться в детали, и написать, что вы используете стандартные криптографические средства .NET Framework, что соответствует действительности и подскажет знающему человеку, о чём речь.

Однако, обычно этот раздел документации должен рассказать, какие именно криптографические средства вы используете сейчас и можно ли их менять по мере устаревания. Поэтому можете ссылаться на названия алгоритмов, благо, все популярные алгоритмы в .NET Framework реализованы.

Answer (score 1):

Напишите, что для кодирование и декодирования используется класс `Название конкретного класса, который вы используйте` из пространства имен `System.Security.Cryptography` (при условии, что данный класс из этого пространства имен). Словосочетание `Используется библиотека Cryptography` будет сбивать с толку, т.к. человек может подумать о какой-то внешней библиотеке.

Comment: Ну вообще это словосочетание будет правильным, допустим человек знает, что предполагается пространство имен?

Comment: Если вы пишите документацию, то ваша цель ясно и доходчиво донести до пользователя нужную информацию. Поэтому указание имени класса и пространства имен позволит более точно конкретизировать, что вы имели ввиду. Т.к. классы с одинаковым именем могут быть расположены в разных пространствах имен.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, пространство имен называть библиотекой нельзя.

Посмотрите в документации или в студии имя сборки, где находятся используемые вами классы - обычно это и будет название библиотеки. Скорее всего, вы используете `System.dll` или `System.Security.dll`.

Но в вашем случае проще сказать - "стандартные библиотеки .NET Framework".

Answer (score 0):

System.Security.Cryptography Пространство имен предоставляет криптографические службы для безопасного шифрования и дешифрования данных, а также множество других операций, таких как хэширование, генерация случайных чисел и проверки подлинности сообщений

Comment: Я знаю, что это. Вопрос в другом...